# SXSSFWorkbook generates corrupted Excel file(xlsx) randomly with Apache POI 412 / 5.2.2

Tags: excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel

SXSSFWorkbook generates corrupted file randomly with Apache POI 412. This issue happens randomly and Once we clear the Cache in the weblogic application server and re-start the server and it works fine. Again after sometime we face the same issue. please find the below sample program and let me know how we can fix this issue.
// Java program to write data in excel sheet using java code

public class TestExcel {

```
private static final String HEADER_FONT = "Calibri"; 
private static final short HEADER_FONT_Height = 11;

// any exceptions need to be caught
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger" );
    System.setProperty("poi.log.level", POILogger.DEBUG + "");
        

    // workbook object
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook =  new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 100, true, true);
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
    
    String workSheetName = "AddressBookData";        
    // Create a sheet
    System.out.println("Before Calling workbook.createSheet");
    Sheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(workSheetName);
    System.out.println("After Calling workbook.createSheet");
    
    //Create a Font for styling header cells
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontName(HEADER_FONT);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints(HEADER_FONT_Height);

    // Create a CellStyle with the font
    CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
            
    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A1");
    int rowIndex = cellReference.getRow();
    int colIndex = cellReference.getCol();
            
    // Create a Row
    Row row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowIndex);
    int headerColIndex = colIndex;


    // This data needs to be written (Object[])
    Map<String, Object[]> addressBookData= new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    addressBookData.put("1", new Object[] { "Address Number", "Alpha Name", "Sch Typ" });
    addressBookData.put("2", new Object[] { "1", "Financial/Distribution Company", "E" });
    addressBookData.put("3", new Object[] { "2", "4242", "C" });
    addressBookData.put("4", new Object[] { "3", "DITTest","E" });
    addressBookData.put("5", new Object[] { "4", "DITTest4","E" });
    addressBookData.put("6", new Object[] { "12", "Test1","E" });
    addressBookData.put("7", new Object[] { "13", "Test2","E" });
    addressBookData.put("8", new Object[] { "14", "Test3","E" });
    addressBookData.put("9", new Object[] { "21", "Test4","E" });
    Set<String> keyid = addressBookData.keySet();

    int rowid = 0;
    // writing the data into the sheets...
    for (String key : keyid) {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
        Object[] objectArr = addressBookData.get(key);
        int cellid = 0;
        for (Object obj : objectArr) {
            if (rowid == 1)
            {
                Cell headerCell = row.createCell(cellid++);               
                headerCell.setCellValue((String)obj);                
                headerCell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
            }
            else
            {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // .xlsx is the format for Excel Sheets...
    // writing the workbook into the file...
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File("AB.xlsx"));

    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    // Closing the workbook
     workbook.close();
     // Delete the the temp file 
     workbook.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: [Apache PO 4.12 is over 2 years old and has lots of bugs fixed since then](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#4.1.2) - try upgrading?

Comment: @ Gagravarr Thanks for the help. I searched the bugs list,could not find any bug which report similar issue. Any specific bug which fixed this issue in latest Apache POI release.? please let me know.

Comment: Try upgrading and see? Failing that, you'll need to ring whoever you pay for support for Apache POI (maybe weblogic provide that when you pay them all that money?), we're all volunteers here and you need to do some of the work yourself...

Comment: We are getting the same issue after Upgrade to Apache POI 5.2.2 randomly. so do we need to set to  workBook.setZip64Mode(Zip64Mode.Never);? please let me know.